# MVC somehow caching embedded views between runs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

My organisation is using Razor Views as embedded files in order to implement an add-on framework for our application.

For some unknown reason the content of the embedded view ends up getting cached across runs. I.e. Run, go to page, Stop, edit add-on view, build add-on, Run, refresh page, old view is used.

Things I've tried:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

and

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.7" debug="true" optimizeCompilations="false">
</system.web>
```

Deleting the bin and obj folders (as much as I can, Razor locks a few files) causes this 'cache' to be reset. This may be as a result of a rebuild. There are no files in either folder which store the add-on views.

The add-ons are loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the cause of this was but I solved the issue by putting the Last Modified Date Time of the assembly with the views in it in to the virtual path that MVC would then use to request the view with.

I get to dictate the virtual path that MVC uses to load the view by overriding `RazorViewEngine` and overriding the `FindView` and `FindPartialView` methods.